# Printing values from a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to print values from a data frame in a sentence.

I have a data frame like the one bellow;

Data

|  | Name | age | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 45 | Male |

when i use a line such as;

```
print('His name is', Data['Name'], 'and he is', Data['age'], 'He is a', Data['Sex'])
```

the issue is that it prints dtype and other info that isn't needed, this means the printed sentence is not in the correct format.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Please add Output of your code and except output you want

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is the most primitive way you can do it. In this example, the .at locator is being used to get a single values using their index value and column name. From your code, `Data['Name']` accesses the entire Name series, where you really just want a single value. Besides .at, you may also employee .loc or .iloc.

```
Data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {1: 'Tom'}, 'age': {1: 45}, 'Sex': {1: 'Male'}})

print('His name is '  + Data.at[ 1, 'Name'] + ' and he is ' + str(Data.at[ 1, 'age'])  + ' He is a', Data.at[1, 'Sex'] + '.')
```

Output:

```
His name is Tom and he is 45 He is a Male.
```

However, I recommend using one of Python's print formatters such as [format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) or [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/). It's worth noting that if the Age column is of type int, than it must be cast to a string with the concatenation method. But the formatters take care of that for you and manual casting is not needed.

```
print('His name is {} and he is {}. He is a {}.'.format(Data.at[ 1, 'Name'] , Data.at[ 1, 'age'], Data.at[1, 'Sex']))
```

Output:

```
His name is Tom and he is 45. He is a Male.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack a series into variables and use f-string print:

```
name, age, sex = df.loc[1]
print(f'His name is, {name}, and he is {age}, He is a {sex}.')
```

Output:

```
His name is, Tom, and he is 45, He is a Male.
```